# How to extract variable from a class with multiple variables, within a list

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm trying to make this program work as a glossary where you're supposed to be able to add your words in two languages. When happy with the number of words you've added you press a button and you can test yourself on those words.

In doing this I eventually ended up making a custom class containing the word in both languages and if it had been used in the word-test before. Now I'm at a stop where I try to fill a textbox with the word from the class that is laying within the list and I can't figure out how to get the data out.

I've tried a bunch of stuff but being a newbie I just dig the hole further and further down and I just can't get up...

```
namespace Uppgift_13._1__Glosprogramet_
{
    public partial class Glosprogram : Form
    {
        List<glosa> glosLista = new List<glosa>();
        Random slump = new Random();
        glosa glosor = new glosa("", "", false);

        int valAvSpråk; //Choice of language
        int valAvGlosa; //Choice of glossary
        string valAvOrd; //Choice of word (glossary and then what language (which word of that glossary))

        public Glosprogram()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void btnLäggTillGlosa_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            /*Här läggs ett objekt in i listan enligt en klass jag skapat som
            innehåller det svenska ordet, den engelska översättningen och ifall den anänts i glostestet.*/
            glosLista.Add( (new glosa(tbxSvensktOrd.Text, tbxEngelsktOrd.Text, false) ) );
            btnStartaGlostest.Enabled = true;
        }

        private void btnStartaGlostest_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            /*Känner vi oss klara med mängden inlagda glosor så kan vi då klicka på starta glostest
             för att testa oss på glosorna. Då låses fönstret för att lägga till nya glosor och 
             ett svenskt eller engelskt ord dyker upp i en av rutorna som man sedan får svara på
             i den andra rutan och också det andra språket då.*/
            gbxLäggTillGlosor.Enabled = false;
            gbxGlostest.Enabled = true;

            // 0=Svenska rutan, 1=Engelska rutan
            valAvSpråk = slump.Next(0, 2);
            valAvGlosa = slump.Next(0, glosLista.Count + 1);
            
            //THIS IS WHERE I AM HAVING MY PROBLEMS... CAN'T QUITE FIGURE IT OUT.

            if(valAvSpråk == 1) //So if english is the language of choice, it should fill that textbox with the random
            {                   //glossary in english and then lock it and let the user answer in Swedish. The rest is comparing the answer to the varibale in the class, within the list, again.. Am lost...
                tbxEngelsktOrdGlostest.Text = "" + glosLista.;
                tbxEngelsktOrdGlostest.ReadOnly = true;
            }

            else
            {

            }
        }

        private void btnSvara_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            glosLista.Insert(valAvGlosa, new glosa(glosor.svenskGlosa, glosor.engelskGlosa, true));
            tbxEngelsktOrdGlostest.Clear();
            tbxSvensktOrdGlostest.Clear();
            tbxResultat.AppendText("" + "\r\n");
        }

        private void btnNyaGlosor_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //Tömma listan på glosor, svenska och engelska, rensa resultatlistan.
            gbxLäggTillGlosor.Enabled = true;
            gbxGlostest.Enabled = false;
        }
    }
}


And then my class that I created for thisnamespace Uppgift_13._1__Glosprogramet_
{
    class glosa
    {
        private string privatSvenskGlosa;          //Swedish translation of word
        private string privatEngelskGlosa;         //English translation of word
        private bool privatAnväntGlostest = false; //Is used in word-test

        public glosa(string msvenskGlosa, string mengelskGlosa, bool manväntGlostest)
        {
            this.svenskGlosa = msvenskGlosa;
            this.engelskGlosa = mengelskGlosa;
            this.använtGlostest = manväntGlostest;
        }

        public string svenskGlosa 
        {
            get
            {
                return privatSvenskGlosa;
            }

            set
            {
                privatSvenskGlosa = value.ToLower();
            }
        }


        /*Samtidigt gör klassen om alla inmatningar till att enbart vara skrivet i små bokstäver
        för att underlätta att hitta i indexet senare samt inte få fel för att man skrivit
        med stor bokstav i början en gång och sedan skriver med liten bokstav en annan.*/
        public string engelskGlosa
        {
            get
            {
                return privatEngelskGlosa;
            }

            set
            {
                privatEngelskGlosa = value.ToLower();
            }
        }

        public bool använtGlostest
        {
            get
            {
                return privatAnväntGlostest;
            }

            set
            {
                privatAnväntGlostest = value;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Your code is harder to read for people that do not speak your language. If you share code that uses English class names, method names, etc, you will probably get help soon.

Comment: Got exactly the help needed, no need to really understand the whole code but just how to get the data out of the class inside the list. List[i].classVariable

Comment: I did not expect that reaction. If you don’t need people to understand your code, don’t post your code. If you want to know “how to get the data out of a list?”, then just ask that and skip the rest. I know you are new to programming, so I understand it may be hard to find the right things to ask. But try to think about “how could I have asked this question better?”

Comment: My previous comment may come across as rough feedback. Realize that I try to help you with my previous comment. I wish you very many happy years of programming and also growth in your skills. Good luck!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

seems like you want to choose a random item from a list

you need

```
               // pick the element from the list
               var glosEnt = glosLista[valAvGlosa];
               if(valAvSpråk == 1)  
               {     
                     tbxEngelsktOrdGlostest.Text = glosEnt.engelskGlosa;
                     tbxEngelsktOrdGlostest.ReadOnly = true;
               }
```

Comment: Thank you, this gave me a different view on my problem.
Didn't quite do it like this but you helped me realize that glosLista[valAvGlosa].engelskGlosa works to access the variables by just changing out the "engelskGlosa" part. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

I will just answer the title’s question “How to extract variable from a class with multiple variables, within a list?”  (I don’t like reading non-English code).

Let’s say you have a list:

```
var list = new List<MyClass>
{ 
    new MyClass { PropertyA = “A”, PropertyB = “B” },
    new MyClass { PropertyA = “1”, PropertyB = “2” }
}
```

First find the instance (of the class) that you need:

```
var obj = list.FirstOrDefault(x => x.PropertyA == “1”);
```

Then get a member’s value:

```
if (obj != null)
{
    var myVariable = obj.PropertyB;
}
```

If you’re sure your search will find the object, then you can use `First` instead of `FirstOrDefault` (both are from the namespace `System.Linq`) and skip the null-check.

If you need a random element:

```
var random = new Random(); // random number generator
var randomElement = list[random.Next(list.Count)];
```

Note about `System.Random`:

It is better to make one instance of the `Random` class and reuse that instead of using it once and creating a new instance for each random number, because if you instantiate the `Random` class, its first value (and the series of numbers that comes next) depends on the current `DateTime` (in .NET Framework) and if instantiated  within a very small time span, those instances may give the same “random” value. More info: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.random?view=net-6.0#instantiating-the-random-number-generator